# How do I turn domain.com/page.php into domain.com/page/?

Tags: .htaccess

Using

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, turn off `Multiviews`.

Second you need a rule that takes a request for `/page.php` and *redirect the browser* to resend a request for `/page/`.

Third, you need a rule that takes the request for `/page/` and *internally rewrite it back* to `/page.php`.

Fourth, you need to make sure any relative links in your pages are either changed to absolute links (starts with a `/`) or add a `<base href="/" />` to the header of your pages.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (GET|HEAD)\ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1.php [L]
```

---

EDIT: you've edited your question.

The reason why you're probably getting the 500 error is that you've got a space after the `L` flag:

```
# you can't have any spaces in your flags--------v
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: What I am trying to do is what this website is doing. http://www.eleven2.com/help/ - Still .htaccess based right?

Comment: @AndB Sorry, missing a `)` after the `([^\?\ ]+`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: The problem with this rule is that if you request a URI where there is no php file for, it'll loop and case a 500 error.